# Selenium IDE has stopped recognising pop-up windows

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I'm relatively new to Selenium and since the update to 1.0.12, when I run my tests, each case with a `selectWindow` command fails. If I run these steps seperately, by clicking individually, it passes, so I know I have the right window ID, etc.

I've tried a `pause`, a `waitForPopup`, `waitForPageToLoad`, `clickAndWait` ... I'm not sure what else to try. I find it odd that this worked last week and all tests passed and now I'm finding that every window is not recognised.

Is anyone else having this problem? And also any more ideas how I can resolve this? (Annoyed that all my tests now fail!)

Thanks,
Sarah

Comment: do you get it working with version prior to "1.0.12" ?

Comment: It updated itself yesterday or the day before, and it worked before that point. I re-run the whole regression pack today and it fails at every 'selectWindow'

Comment: "updated it self" How did it update it self :-/ If you suspect a defect then I would request you to post it here with all possible details - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-developers

Comment: I mean the latest build when I say 'updated itself'.  Selenium was updated to v. 1.0.12 - and I didn't request the update so was automatic. I've had a look on the selenium site at the defects and I think this is a logged defect already - #1923

Answer (score 3):

Known bug.

This build is supposed to fix this issue, but is not an official release yet so YMMV.

http://xserve.openqa.org:8085/browse/IDE-IDE-125/artifact

Comment: Thanks, stupid question - how do I download this? I get a 'do you want to save this file, or find a program online to open it' popup.

Comment: Might help if I actually downloaded it in firefox...whoops.  Thanks that seems to have worked! :o)

Comment: heh :) (gah I need to make a long comment)